# Git status in machine readable format with paths relative to current directory

Tags: git

Is it possible to make `git status` output in machine readable format (`-z`) but with paths relative to current directory (`-s`)?

Currently when I use `-z -s` paths are formatted as relative to repo root instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
git status -z | sed "s:\(^\|\x00\).. :\0$(git rev-parse --show-cdup):g"
```

This command gets the relative path to the root directory and injects it into the status output, so that the paths are relative to the current working directory again.

**DISCLAIMER:** This `sed` script might not work on all versions of `sed`.

Comment: This `sed` doesn't work on FreeBSD (not sure about MacOS). I think it's that sed regex doesn't work with embedded NULs, although there may be other issues too. But this is generally the right idea: we have to fix things up after the fact, using `--show-cdup` results.

Comment: @torek I have no FreeBSD available. Tell me how to do it correctly on FreeBSD and I'll happily update my answer.

Comment: I'd use a more-capable filter-er, perhaps Perl (though I really hate Perl :-) ). Or just do it in whatever is machine-reading the `git status -z` machine-readable output...

Comment: But Perl is not necessarily installed. On a Git for Windows or Cygwin installation for example. Besides that, if OP wants to use perl or whatever tool he uses to read the data, he can read the answer as recipe on how to do it. ;-)

Comment: True. (I tend to write these kinds of things in Python myself, these days, but not all installations have Python either.) I suppose it's worth just noting that not all `sed`s can handle this as a caveat, and otherwise just keeping the answer as "here's the idea"...